# error : "A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception: The function requested is not supported" Between WPF app and Java Server app, com: WebSocket)

Tags: c#, websocket

I have a .Net WPF Desktop application write in C#, which communicate with a Java server application using Websocket.
The TSL (Transport Security Layer) of the server application has been recently updated from the 1.1 to 1.2 version.
Since then the client was not able to connect again to the server.
I received the following error; “An error occurred: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception: The function requested is not supported”

The .Net framework has been raised from 4.6.1 to 4.7.2 and the registry has been created as it mentioned in the documentation

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client

A DWORD entry named DisabledByDefault with 0 as value
Another DWORD entry named Enabled with 1 as value both in hexadecimal format.

Any idea ?

Comment: Dear I put "ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12"  in the function that initialize the web socket but I still have the same error. How can I implement the second option ?  to select TLS to use Operating System in config file ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls?force_isolation=true

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls?force_isolation=true. The ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol is equivalent to modifying the registry.  If you are using a Mobile device the Kernel may need updating.  Microsoft has in Windows all latest TLS encryption modes in their security pushes.

Comment: during instantiation of the WebSocket class I put in the constructor parameters the specific  version of TLS I want to use (TLS 1.2) => 'WebSocket = new WebSocket(WebsocketAlertFullUrl, String.Empty, 
                null, CustomHeaderItems, String.Empty, String.Empty, WebSocketVersion.Rfc6455, 
                null, SslProtocols.Tls12);'  And now it works  !